# Jquery validate click submit button twice ASP.Net core MVC project

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, visual-studio, jquery-validate

I seem to cannot find a solution for this issue. I have searched and none of the approach persons took seem to apply to my situation.

```
$(document).on("submit", "#createDriverForm", function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $("#createDriverForm").validate({
        ignore: null,
        rules: {
            driversLicenceCountryId: {
                requiredselect: 0
            },
            driversLicenceNumber: "required",
            firstName: "required",
            lastName: "required",
            genderId: {
                requiredselect: 0
            },
            dateOfBirth: "required",
            driversLicenceDateIssued: "required",
            driversLicenceExpiryDate: "required",
            driversLicenceTypeId: {
                requiredselect: 0
            },
            driversLicenceFirstIssued: "required"
        },
        //For custom messages
        messages: {
            driversLicenceCountryId: {
                requiredselect: "Please select your country of licence"
            },
            driversLicenceNumber: "Please enter driver's licence number",
            firstName: "Please enter your first name",
            lastName: "Please enter your last name",
            genderId: "Please select your gender",
            dateOfBirth: {
                requiredselect: "Please enter your date of birth"
            },
            driversLicenceDateIssued: "Please enter your driver's licence issue date",
            driversLicenceExpiryDate: "Please enter your driver's licence expiry date",
            driversLicenceTypeId: {
                requiredselect: "Please select licence type"
            },
            driversLicenceFirstIssued: "Please enter your driver's licence first issue date"
        },
        errorElement: "div",
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            var placement = $(element).data('error');
            if (placement) {
                $(placement).append(error);
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function () {

            var driverModal = $("[data-remodal-id=driver]").remodal();

            $.ajax({
                beforeSubmit: ProcessingModal("Saving driver details. Please hold...."),
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Quote/SaveDriverDetails",
                data: $("#createDriverForm", modal).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    SuccessSwalWithCallback(data,
                        function () {
                            driverModal.close();
                            window.location.reload();
                        });
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    ErrorSwal(data.responseText);
                }
            });
        },
        invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
            Notice(`Please ensure all required fields are entered. Number of invalid fields: ${validator.numberOfInvalids()}`);
        }
    });

});
```

I have a form that is dynamically rendered via the server and then is displayed on a modal. Whenever I click the save button which is of type submit on the form. I realize I have to make a click again before the validate effect is triggered. I need assistance to figure out the approach to take please.

NB. Whenever I take out the

```
$(document).on("submit", "#createDriverForm", function (e)
```

Then the form gets posted normally and the page reload and the validate is not triggered.

---

**Edit:** For a little more understanding about how the form is populated on the DOM.

```
<div id="driverModal" class="remodal b-top-red" data-remodal-id="driver" style="max-width: 80%" data-remodal-options="closeOnOutsideClick: false">
        <button data-remodal-action="close" class="remodal-close"></button>
        <div id="driverContent"></div>
    </div>
```

I have a modal and whenever the user click "View/Edit" on the page then the server returns the `<form id="createDriverForm">......</form>` via `$("#driverContent").html(data)`. i.e. data being the form. Solidifying my explanation when I said the form is rendered dynamically.

Comment: So you click -> nothing happens, validation passes -> click again, then it submits?

Comment: "#createDriverForm" is that a <form> element or <div> element?

Comment: @lloyd Yes, that's what happens.

Comment: @Goontracker It's a `<form>` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out the solution. Had to check for when the modal with the form is populated first then call validate.

```
$(document).on("opened", "#driverModal", function(){});
```

That checks for when the modal is opened then I call validate cause now then the form would exist in the DOM.

```
$(document).on("opened",
    "#driverModal",
    function () {
        $("#createDriverForm").validate({
            ignore: null,
            rules: {
                driversLicenceCountryId: {
                    requiredselect: 0
                },
                driversLicenceNumber: "required",
                firstName: "required",
                lastName: "required",
                genderId: {
                    requiredselect: 0
                },
                dateOfBirth: "required",
                driversLicenceDateIssued: {
                    required: true
                },
                driversLicenceExpiryDate: {
                    required: true
                },
                driversLicenceTypeId: {
                    requiredselect: 0
                },
                driversLicenceFirstIssued: "required"
            },
            //For custom messages
            messages: {
                driversLicenceCountryId: {
                    requiredselect: "Please select your country of licence"
                },
                driversLicenceNumber: "Please enter driver's licence number",
                firstName: "Please enter your first name",
                lastName: "Please enter your last name",
                genderId: "Please select your gender",
                dateOfBirth: {
                    requiredselect: "Please enter your date of birth"
                },
                driversLicenceDateIssued: "Please enter your driver's licence issue date",
                driversLicenceExpiryDate: "Please enter your driver's licence expiry date",
                driversLicenceTypeId: {
                    requiredselect: "Please select licence type"
                },
                driversLicenceFirstIssued: "Please enter your driver's licence first issue date"
            },
            errorElement: "div",
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                var placement = $(element).data("error");
                if (placement) {
                    $(placement).append(error);
                } else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                $.ajax({
                    beforeSubmit: ProcessingModal("Saving driver details. Please hold...."),
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Quote/SaveDriverDetails",
                    data: $(form).serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        SuccessSwalWithCallback(data,
                            function () {
                                driverModal.close();
                                window.location.reload();
                            });
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        ErrorSwal(data.responseText);
                    }
                });
            },
            invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
                Notice(`You seem to have missed ${validator
                    .numberOfInvalids()} field. Please enter the missing information`);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to have $(document).on("submit".....).
If "#createDriverForm" is a  element, change the submitHandler() to the following.
https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

```
$("#createDriverForm").validate({

    submitHandler: function(form) {
       $(form).ajaxSubmit();    
});
```

Comment: "#createDriverForm" does not exist on the DOM until the server return that from to the modal on the view. Hence why I did the `$(document).on("click", "#createDriverForm", function(){})`. I tried your suggestion but its being submitted normally and not via ajax. I defined `var options = {};` with my ajax options and passed it into `$(form).ajaxSubmit(options)`. Thinking because `#createDriverForm` does not exist on page load that the event handler for `.validate()` was not set up.

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple you need to put your validation code on $(document).ready function. So it became part of loaded document. When you will click on relevant submit button or when you will submit form using any way. You will hit validation code in first click.

That's All

Comment: In some cases for dynamically loaded code can be capture in ajax completed event too on document level.

Comment: I did have it in a $(document).ready function but it still did not hit the validate